# Firebase - user and currentUser nil within closure

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm having issues with Firebase where my attempt to get a `uid` variable with `Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` seems to return nil.

I've placed various print statements around the function (I've posted the full function below) to see if they get called - if I place a print statement within `if let user = user`, it does not get called. If I comment out `if let user = user` (and its closing bracket), the print statement is called successfully, so I guess `user` is nil.

Now, if I place the print after `guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}`, the print statement is again not called, leading me to believe that `uid` is nil and the guard statement is returning out.

I'm not sure why `user` and `Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` are both nil here. How can I change this to successfully get my `uid` variable?

Here is the full function to provide some context:

```
@IBAction func emailSignupNextPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // Make sure text fields aren't empty
    guard nameField.text != "", emailField.text != "", passwordField.text != "", confirmPasswordField.text != "" else {return}

    if passwordField.text == confirmPasswordField.text {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            if let user = user {

                guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}

                // Use name as Firebase display name for readability
                let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser!.createProfileChangeRequest()
                changeRequest.displayName = self.nameField.text!
                changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: nil)

                // Create child node from userStorage "users". Profile image set to user's unique ID
                let imageRef = self.userStorage.child("\(uid).jpg")
                let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.selectProfileImageView.image!, 0.5)

                // Upload image to Firebase
                let uploadTask = imageRef.putData(data!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in
                    if err != nil {
                                                    print(err!.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, er) in
                        if er != nil {
                                                            print(er?.localizedDescription as Any)
                        }
                        if let url = url {


                            emailUserPicString = url.absoluteString
                            print("\n\n\npic:\(emailUserPicString)\n\n\n")

                            if emailUserPicString == "" {

                                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Profile Picture Error", message: "Don't forget to choose a profile picture!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(alert :UIAlertAction!) in
                                })
                                alertController.addAction(okAction)

                                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                                return

                            } else {
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "emailToSetup", sender: nil)
                            }





                        }
                    })
                })
                uploadTask.resume()
            }
        })
    } else {
        print("Passwords don't match")
        passwordAlert()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`auth().currentUser` will return a `user` only when a user is signed in.

You have just created this user, so it is not signed in.

You can usually get the `uid` from the `user` passed into the block, e.g.:

```
let uid = user.uid
```

If `user` is null, account creation has failed and you should inspect the error. I notice you are using

```
print(error.localizedDescription)
```

but you may want to use:

```
print(error)
```

in case the error doesn't have a localized description.

Typically an error either means a networking issue, or that the user already has an account.

---

BTW, if you want to sign the user in, you can use

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { … }
```

Comment: So I tried changing my guard statement within `if let user = user` to `guard let uid = user.uid else {return}` but I get an error `Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'uid'`. Also, do I need to keep the `if let` to force unwrap `user` here? As I mentioned in my OP, it seems that `user` is nil i.e. anything after `if let user = user` is not called.